# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-cognitive-services

I'm Trying out the `Azure Cognitive Service Vision API` for android. My gradle version is `3.1.2`. And I add the dependencies for using the Vision API as:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:vision:1.0.394'
}
```

And when I try to build the app it give me an error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
```

Tried out with googling and everything but can't get around this error.